# ipv6 - how to make network hosts ignore advertised DNS

Tags: dhcp, home-networking, ipv6, dnsmasq

On my home network I have:

- Router provided by my ISP. DHCP server switched off in its configuration
- Raspberry Pi, running dnsmasq (among other things), providing DHCP and DNS servers.

The Raspberry Pi DNS server has custom names for internal services, so I want this to be the only DNS server that is being used for all network clients.

For IPv4, this works fine.

However, for IPv6, all is not well, because the ISP router is advertising itself as a name server, and the devices on the network are adding this server to their list, and sometimes attempting to use it for name resolution.

The ISP router sends out IPv6 Router Advertisements, and there doesn't seem to be a way to configure this or turn it off.

How do I tell network clients that they should ignore the name servers advertised by the ISP router, and only use the one that's being provided by the Raspberry Pi over DHCP?

I'm aware that dnsmasq's DHCP server has some DHCPv6 options, but these are currently not enabled. The DHCP server is running on IPv4 only. Can this problem be solved by turning on the right DHCPv6 server options on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: No, you cannot override the other device by setting up a DHCPv6 server - they will just compete. There should be a toggle setting for it, but if you are unable to disable Router Advertisements on the router, then you should disable IPv6 on the client side.